# Jenkins run maven project through script instead of Maven Goal

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have the following pre build script in Jenkins:

```
#!/bin/sh set +e
kill $(lsof -t -i:8081)
mvn -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project clean package
java -jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/target/site-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

My Maven Goal is empty,
[image]

when I run Build I have the following error message

```
> /usr/bin/git rev-list --no-walk 044c84323d27dc3ceee93c5eebbd1c59162b6561 # timeout=10
[giant-web] $ /bin/sh -e /tmp/jenkins6442992288874687975.sh
/tmp/jenkins6442992288874687975.sh: 2: kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

How to fix it and what is the problem because this script work fine from terminal

Comment: *My Maven Goal is empty,* what do you mean by that ?

Comment: But anyway, seems like you havean error in your sh.script.

Comment: @Antoniossss update my question

Comment: @Antoniossss script works fine if I run it from terminal

Comment: Script is faulty no matter what you say. In this case either `$(lsof -t -i:8081)` resolves to empty string or non pid value thus the error.

Comment: @Antoniossss So what is my way to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script is faulty for some reasons. Either $(lsof -t -i:8081) resolves to empty string or non pid value thus the error.

```
[giant-web] $ /bin/sh -e /tmp/jenkins6442992288874687975.sh
/tmp/jenkins6442992288874687975.sh: 2: kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]
```

This block states clearly that kill is *misused*

Add debuging printout to see what is the value of that statement.

```
SET PID=$(lsof -t -i:8081)
echo "PID value: $PID"
kill $PID
```

also check man for `kill` to make sure you got it right and you don't need any additional switch.